# $\pi_0(GL_2(\mathbb{R}))$

Tags: general-topology, matrices

For a topological space $X$ we define $\pi_0(X)$ to be the quotient of $X$ by the equivalence relation, that two points are equivalent if there is a path joining them.  Now I have $X=GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ with the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^4$. I already found out that this space is the disjoint union of the sets of matrices with determinant bigger than zero respectively less than zero. I also know that they are homeomorphic to each other. My guess is that they are path-connected. But I can't show this. Does anybody have a hint?

Answer (score 4):

There is a path from $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ with $ad-bc>0$ to the identity:

- First, if $d\ne 0$ vary $t$ in  $\begin{pmatrix}a+tb&b\\c+td&d\end{pmatrix}$ until $c$ becomes $0$.
- Then vary $t$ in $\begin{pmatrix}a&b+td\\0&d\end{pmatrix}$ (or $\begin{pmatrix}a+tc&b\\c&0\end{pmatrix}$) until $b$ (or $a$) is zero
- Now you can vary $a$ and $d$ (or $b$ and $c$) without crossing zero to arrive at one of $\begin{pmatrix}\pm1&0\\0&\pm1\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0&\pm1\\\mp1&0\end{pmatrix}$
- These can be brougth to the identity matrix along $\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&\sin t\\-\sin t &\cos t\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: That's a very nice solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The classical proof that $\mathrm{GL}(n, \, \mathbb{R})$ has precisely two path-connected components uses the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition), and can be found in F. W. Warner's book *[Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-1799-0)*, see in particular Theorem 3.68.